# Mysql Auto Backup on ubuntu server

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, ubuntu, backup

After months of trying to get this to happen I found a shell script that will get the job done.

Heres the code I'm working with

```
#!/bin/bash
### MySQL Server Login Info ###
MUSER="root"
MPASS="MYSQL-ROOT-PASSWORD"
MHOST="localhost"
MYSQL="$(which mysql)"
MYSQLDUMP="$(which mysqldump)"
BAK="/backup/mysql"
GZIP="$(which gzip)"
### FTP SERVER Login info ###
FTPU="FTP-SERVER-USER-NAME"
FTPP="FTP-SERVER-PASSWORD"
FTPS="FTP-SERVER-IP-ADDRESS"
NOW=$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")

### See comments below ###
### [ ! -d $BAK ] && mkdir -p $BAK || /bin/rm -f $BAK/* ###
[ ! -d "$BAK" ] && mkdir -p "$BAK"

DBS="$($MYSQL -u $MUSER -h $MHOST -p$MPASS -Bse 'show databases')"
for db in $DBS
do
 FILE=$BAK/$db.$NOW-$(date +"%T").gz
 $MYSQLDUMP -u $MUSER -h $MHOST -p$MPASS $db | $GZIP -9 > $FILE
done

lftp -u $FTPU,$FTPP -e "mkdir /mysql/$NOW;cd /mysql/$NOW; mput /backup/mysql/*; quit" $FTPS
```

Everything is running great, however there are a few things I'd like to fix but am clueless when it comes to shell scripts. I'm not asking anyone to write it. Just some pointers. First of all the /backup/mysql directory on my server stacks the files everytime it backs up. Not to big of a deal. But after a year of nightly backups it might get a little full. So id like it to clear that directory after uploading. Also I don't want to overload my hosting service with files so id like it to clear the remote servers dir before uploading. Lastly I would like it to upload to a subdirectory on the remote server such as /mysql

Answer (score 0):

Why reinvent the wheel? You can just use [Debian](http://debian.org)'s [automysqlbackup](https://packages.debian.org/unstable/automysqlbackup) package (should be available on Ubuntu as well).

As for cleaning old files the following command might be of help:

```
find /mysql -type f -mtime +16 -delete
```

Uploading to remote server can be done using `scp`(1) command;
To avoid password prompt read about [SSH public key authentication](https://lmddgtfy.net/?q=SSH%20public%20key%20authentication)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Backup](http://meskyanichi.github.io/backup/v4/), it allows you to model your backup jobs using a Ruby DSL, very powerful.

Support multiple DBs and most popular online storages, and lots of cool features.